# Messed up encoding using htlatex

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8

I just used tex4ht and htlatex to convert a latex document into html, and now i have some serious trouble to integrate this html document in a web site i'm making (I'm using Laravel though).
I think one of the reason I have some troubles is that htlatex output files are Unix encoded, not utf-8.
 If I just input the file using Laravel views and controllers without any modification, utf-8 characters are not displayed, and if i convert the file to utf-8, all utf-8 characters turn weird within notepad and I have to rewrite them one at a time (the html files contains 2000+ lines, I can't do that).
I'm wondering how can I solve the problem.
Is "puting the input html in an iframe" tag an any good solution ? Or is there a way to encode this file to utf-8 without messing with his content ? I'm so lost....

Comment: There's no such thing as "Unix encoding". You might refer to the Unix line endings, but this is a separate problem (and it shouldn't be a problem at all in a HTML file). Does the HTML file have an encoding declaration? If so you need to find out if it is correct: open the file in an editor (maybe a more powerful one than notepad) which supports specifying the encoding.

Comment: Actually i found out that notepad show how the file is encoded, and it appear to be ISO 8859-1, that's the reason why encoding it in utf-8 right away messed it up. I copied the content in a utf-8 new file, and it worked... don't know if that's the proper way to solve the problem though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tex4ht` uses Latin1 as the default encoding, characters unsupported by this encoding are output as XML entities. You can request `UTF-8` output using the following command:

```
htlatex filename.tex "xhtml,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

As an alternative, you can use [Make4ht](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/make4ht?lang=en) with `-u` option:

```
make4ht -u filename.tex
```

`make4ht` is replacement for `htlatex` with much more features.